# In cypress, where is the because() function?

Tags: chai, cypress

Writing cypress tests with chai assertions, how should I surface the reason behind an assertion in the test output? My test output describes clearly what has failed, but there's no contextual information, and no easy way to go straight to the line number of a failing assertion in the test script. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be nothing provided, but it's really simple to do. Here then is a `because()` custom command that simply **prints it's argument to the command log**, then returns the previous subject, so you can chain it.

```
// sby add context to ouput...
Cypress.Commands.add("because", { prevSubject: 'true'}, (subject, options) => { 
    Cypress.log({
        message: options
    });
    return subject;
})
```

To use it...

```
cy.get("input#date").because("today is today").should("have.value", localToday);
```

That gives you...

[image]

I'm still new to this business, but I like this solution because its fluent, improves the clarity of the output, and I can much more quickly locate the line of code when things are failing.

Answer (score 0):

Using screenshots will answer your questions.

Cypress wil default make screenshots when a test fail (this behaviour can be turned off by putting `"screenshotOnRunFailure":false` in the config). These screenshots are found here: cypress/screenshots

The screenshots capture the test `describe()`, the `it()` and the specific action that fails. If an assertion fails it even mentions what value was expected and what value was retrieved.

Those three outputs inside the screenshot will deliver you an exact place in the test where the failure is.

Answer (score 0):

You can add context to `expect(...).to...`-style assertions like so:

```js
expect(true).to.eq(true, 'should equal itself')
```

[image: screenshot of test in Cypress]

To my knowledge, there is not a way to add context to the `.should()`-style assertions.